# how to disable other check box if one or more check box is checked

Tags: c#

I am doing a c# windows form application. Right now, I have a list of checkbox which I put it in an array. I have a loop to loop through the list of checkbox to do stuff. I am wondering is there a way to disable other checkbox that isn't checked?. Here is my code, help will be appreciated. Thanks. For example, let say checkbox 1 and 6 is checked, then checkbox 2,3,4,5 will be disabled.

Code:

```
CheckBox[] myCheckBoxArray = new CheckBox[6];

myCheckBoxArray [0] = checkBox1;
myCheckBoxArray [1] = checkBox2;
myCheckBoxArray [2] = checkBox3;
myCheckBoxArray [3] = checkBox4;
myCheckBoxArray [4] = checkBox5;
myCheckBoxArray [5] = checkBox6;

foreach (CheckBox checkBox in myCheckBoxArray )
{
    if (checkBox .Text == className && comboBox1.SelectedIndex == index) 
    {
        checkBox .Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do:

```
 public void DisableAllUnchecked(IEnumerable<CheckBox> items)
 {
      items.ForEach(m=> m.Enabled = !m.Checked);
 }
```

Sample Code:

```
 DisableAllUnckeched(myCheckBoxArray);
```

Or if you don't want to create a method you can do it in a single line:

```
myCheckBoxArray.ToList().ForEach(m=> m.Enabled = !m.Checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify foreach loop as below:

```
foreach(CheckBox checkBox in myCheckBoxArray) 
{   
    if (checkBox.Text == className && comboBox1.SelectedIndex == index) 
    {
        checkBox.Checked = true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        checkBox.Checked = false;
        checkBox.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//put an else after your if    
foreach (CheckBox checkBox in myCheckBoxArray )
{    
    if (checkBox .Text == className && comboBox1.SelectedIndex == index) {    
        checkBox .Checked = true;        
    }
    else
    {
         checkBox .Enabled= false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this would do the trick

```
foreach(CheckBox checkBox in myCheckBoxArray)
{
    if(checkBox.IsChecked==false)
    {
        checkBox.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will enable the same checkbox that is unchecked, for each checkbox. It doesn't do what OP asks for in the question, and it doesn't take into account the 'one or more' condition.